# How to install derelict using dsss and dmd

Tags: d, dsss

I'm starting with the D programming language and I wanted to do some graphics programming stuff with OpenGL, so I understand the way to go is to use the Derelict bindings.

Now, I installed the DMD 2 compiler, also DSSS, but I'm having trouble installing derelict using `dsss net install derelict`. It says that "gdc is not in $PATH". I don't understand if the install needs the gdc compiler or what. Can I change dsss to use dmd instead?

Also, bonus question, does Derelict support D2 or do I need Derelict2?

EDIT: I'm on OSX 10.7

Comment: DSSS is too old. I do not think it is maintained at all. Try DUB instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Derelict2 (or eventually the newest Derelict3). Just checkout the relevant branch on the dsource svn (or github for Derelict3).

What I do is just compiling the Derelict sources I need and link it with my own code, without making a static library first.

Can't help you with DSSS, or what would be a suitable D build system on OS X.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check Derelict3!

Answer (score 1):

For a more Modern answer, `brew install dmd dub` and then follow the instructions at http://dblog.aldacron.net/derelict-help/using-derelict/ . Here is an example of my dub.json file as an example:

```
{
   "name": "dengine",
   "description": "A little game engine.",
   "authors": ["Matthew Clark"],
   "homepage": "http://example.com",
   "license": "GPL-2.0",
   "dependencies": {
     "derelict-sdl2":"~master",
     "derelict-assimp3":"~master",
     "derelict-gl3":"~master"
   }
}
```

Then you just run `dub` and it's a beautiful thing!

Comment: Placing derelict-gl3 ~master to /Users/andrea/.dub/packages/...
WARNING: A deprecated branch based version specification is used for the dependency derelict-gl3. Please use numbered versions instead. Also note that you can still use the dub.selections.json file to override a certain dependency to use a branch instead.